# Making a scheduling application in rails with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to make an app that will display every day of the week, but you will have a previous button and a next button that will show either the previous week or the next week. It should default to this week of course, i was wondering how can i do this using rails and jquery. I just need to brain storm with someone, or if someone has done something similar in their app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several Ruby gem out there that can help you with that.

Check out [jquery_datepicker](https://github.com/albertopq/jquery_datepicker)

Also take a look at [THIS](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) for more customization of your calendar.

If you need more "visual" information checkout the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars?view=comments) on calendars.